# Internal Server Error phpMyAdmin CentOs

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

my site is running great as it should but today i had to loggin to phpMyAdmin and i keep getting Internal Server Error.
i have chacked all permissions etc but no luck
phpMyAdmin is located in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin iam using CentOS and as webpanel CentOS WEBPANEL? any ideas what could the problem be here is my error log

```
[Sun Apr 05 19:24:15 2009] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Apr 05 19:24:15 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Apr 05 19:24:15 2009] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Apr 05 19:24:15 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 05 19:26:23 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Apr 05 19:28:34 2009] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Apr 05 19:28:34 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Apr 05 19:28:34 2009] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Apr 05 19:28:34 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 05 19:36:24 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:08 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:08 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:08 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:08 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:32 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:33 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:34 2014] [error] [client ip] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:36 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:53 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:57 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:39:58 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:41:25 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:50:49 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:50:52 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:50:55 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:50:57 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:51:00 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:51:06 2014] [error] [client ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:53:18 2014] [error] [client my ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:53:18 2014] [error] [client my ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:53:22 2014] [error] [client my ip] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Dec 30 16:55:19 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 30 16:55:20 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 30 16:55:20 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 30 16:55:20 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 30 16:55:20 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 30 16:56:19 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: looks like a permission issue with perhaps the PHP or MySQL user not being able to access the /var/www/html/ dir. Have you tried opening up the permission just to test?

Comment: Yes i did :( maybe more info ?

Comment: Anyway why would it need to access it i dnt have www file even ? iam running my sites from /home ?

Comment: Because phpMyAdmin is running in that folder?

Comment: No !!! it isnt, the phpMyAdmin is in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin where phpMyAdmin is its folder !

Answer (score 0):

Your apache configuration is not setup to serve the php admin files.

[http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html][1]

Alias /usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin /phpMyAdmin

In a .conf file should solve the issue.

You will then be able to access it via /phpMyAdmin